# google charts not redrawing new values on loop

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create an updating real time chart with google chart API's and javascript, but I can't seem to get the chart to update. I got the chart to draw but when when my update data script runs again it calls the function to draw the google chart again because it received new data from my custom library.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TheWayWardJourney</title>
        <script src="cynergi.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script>
            function updateData(){
                // this is retrieving rows from the db and looping through them.
                var data = Cynergi.get('http://:3000/computer_stats?order=time.asc');
                var data_array = []
                $.each( data, function( i, item ) {

                    html_insert = 'Computer Name:' + item.computer_name + '<br>Operating System:' + item.operating_system + '<br>CPU Model: ' + item.cpu_model + '<br>Cores Assigned: ' + item.cores + '<br>CPU MHz: ' + item.cpu_mhz + '<br>CPU Cache: ' + item.cpu_cache + '<br>Net Devices: ' + item.net_devices + '<br>Devices: ' + item.devices;

                    stats = 'Total Memory: ' + item.total_memory + '<br>Free Memory:' + item.free_memory  + '<br> Active Memory:' + item.active_memory + '<br> Bounce Memory:' + item.bounce_memory + '<br> Buffered Memory:' + item.buffers_memory + '<br> Locked Memory:' + item.locked_memory + '<br> Swap Memory:' + item.swap_memory + '<br> Swap Free:' + item.swapfree_memory
                        var time = new Date(parseInt(item.time))
                        data_array.push([{v: time.toString()}, {v: parseInt(item.cpu_usage)}]);
                });
                    drawCharts(data_array);
                    $( "#computer_info" ).html(html_insert);
                    $( "#computer_stats" ).html(stats);
                    setTimeout(function(){  updateData(); }, 30000);
            }
            updateData();
            function update_messages(){
                var message_data = Cynergi.get('http://:3000/page_contact?order=time.asc');
                var message_insert = '';
                $.each( message_data, function( i, item ) {
                    var time = new Date(parseInt(item.time))
                    message_insert = message_insert + '<p>From: ' +item.name+ '</p><p>Message: ' + item.message + '</p><p>Email: ' + item.email + '</p><p>Time: ' + time + '</p><button onclick="delete_post(' + item.id + ')">Delete</button>'

                });
                    $( "#messages" ).html(message_insert);
                    setTimeout(function(){  update_messages(); }, 1000);
            }
            update_messages();
            //this is how you insert into the db
            var d = new Date();
            var time = d.getTime();
            var post = {"name":"Grant Zukel","email":"Test Email","message":"Test Message","read":"no","username":"zukeru","time":time};
            var json_data = post;
            Cynergi.insert('http://:3000/page_contact', json_data);
            //this is how you delete from the db
            function delete_post(id){
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?')) {                      Cynergi.delete('http://m:3000/page_contact?id=eq.' + id);
                }
            }
            //this is how you do an update to teh db
            var d = new Date();
            var time = d.getTime();
            var post = {"name":"Grant Zukel","email":"Test Email@fuckaroasdasd","message":"Test Message UPDATED","read":"no","username":"zukeruasdasd","time":time};
            var json_data = post;
            Cynergi.update('http://:3000/page_contact?id=eq.26', json_data);
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( "#computer_info" ).html(html_insert);
                $( "#computer_stats" ).html(stats);
                $( "#sentStatus" ).html(sentStatus);
                $( "#deleteStatus" ).html(deleteStatus);
                $( "#updateStatus" ).html(updateStatus);
                $( "#messages" ).html(message_insert);
            });
            function drawCharts(data_array){
                google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                      data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
                      data.addColumn('number', 'CPU Usage');
                      data.addRows(data_array);
                      var options = {
                        chart: {
                          title: "Playground's %% CPU Usage",
                          subtitle: 'you know you likie.'
                        },
                        width: 900,
                        height: 500
                  };
                  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));
                  console.log(chart);
                  chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='updateStatus'></p></p>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='sentStatus'></p></p>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='deleteStatus'></p></p>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='computer_info'></p></p>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='computer_stats'></p></p>
        <p style='text-align:left;align:left;' id='messages'></p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what your asking.  I get you want the chart to update but I'm unclear on what you dislike about the current behavior.  Your updateData function explicitly calls drawCharts but I get the impression that you don't want it to.

At first glance it looks like drawCharts would call drawChart each time which would cause the whole chart to be recreated (as opposed to just refreshing the data.)  However, I think the on load callback will only execute once, in this case, causing no updates.  That seems to be verified by [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ps68293y/).

Based on that I'm assuming that the issue isn't that drawCharts is being called multiple times forcing a full redo of everything and that your issue is that when it is called multiple times it isn't redrawing the charts at all.

To fix that issue I would change drawCharts into two functions like this:

```
var chartLibraryIsLoaded = false;


function drawCharts(data_array) {
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
        data.addColumn('number', 'CPU Usage');
        data.addRows(data_array);
        var options = {
            chart: {
                title: "Playground's %% CPU Usage",
                subtitle: 'you know you likie.'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart'));
        console.log(chart);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    if (chartLibraryIsLoaded) {
        drawCharts();
    } else {
        google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
            packages: ['line']
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            chartLibraryIsLoaded = true;
            drawCharts();
        });
    }
}
```

There is a lot about this approach that I don't like but I wanted to make the smallest change I could.  I personally would rework this to not use the global variable and avoid redefining drawChart.

Even if it isn't what you were asking, I would consider refactoring this to also avoid recreating the DataTable and chart and instead manipulate the data in the DataTable and redrawing the chart.